# Can I clear all topics after I kill all nodes?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have kill all nodes by :rosnode kill -a
however, when I type: rostopic list
a list of topics are there ,so Can I remove the topics created before?

waiting for answers,thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40732/can-i-clear-all-topics-after-i-kill-all-nodes?/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-08-07**:
Have you verified all nodes are gone via `rosnode list` afterwards? -- I regularly end up with zombie nodes and their topics, too, and the only way I found to get rid of them is restarting the roscore.

**Comment by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on 2012-08-09**:
How to restart roscore?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-09**:
Alternatively, you can do a `rosnode cleanup`. It will try to ping all nodes that are registered at the core and remove them if they are not running.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-08-13**:
@Lorenz Great find, assuming it works. But why isn't there any documentation about this subcommand?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Ticketed at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess it's only the /rosout topics?
Those come from `roscore`, so all non-core topics are gone.

If others are left, the node might either be still running or the master hasn't realized it's gone properly.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-09-15**:
There's a hidden command rosnode cleanup which might clear the extra state.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosnode cleanup

---

Originally posted by [bluefolder54](https://answers.ros.org/users/21325/bluefolder54/) with karma: 11 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1